# What is the Python list or NumPy equivalent of Excel's SUMIF function?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a 2D array:

```
expenses = np.array([['jim', 'sam', 'bill', 'sam'],[1,2,6,5]])
```

I want to know the total expenses for each unique person in a new array without hardcoding any names (real list is very long) so that I get an output like this:

```
totals = [['jim', 'sam', 'bill'],[1,7,6]]
```

Is there a way of doing this with a list or NumPy? I don't want to use Pandas for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use pandas?   This is a simple `groupby` in pandas, but in numpy you could iterate over the keys, index, and then sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
names = np.asarray(['jim', 'sam', 'bill', 'sam'])
values = np.asarray([1, 2, 6, 5])
result = {name: values[names == name].sum() for name in np.unique(names)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Chet! I see your code works, but when I try to translate it to my script I get a 'could not convert string to float' error for the names. Not quite sure why it's trying to convert the names into numbers.

I'm loading my data with:
`names, values = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True, dtype='str'`

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix it by separating each column into an array with its specific dtype:

`namess = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='str', usecols=[0])
values = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='int', usecols=[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Another fun way to do this (without numpy) is using a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
names = ['jim', 'sam', 'bill', 'sam']
counts = [1,2,6,5]
c = Counter()
for name, count in zip(names,counts):
    c[name] += count
# Remapping of dict to list of lists
list(map(list, zip(*c.items())))
```

Output:

```
[['sam', 'jim', 'bill'], [7, 1, 6]]
```